# generators for argument values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble understanding generators when they are used as arguments. Here are a couple cases where I don't fully understand the source of the errors, or at least how to work around them. Explicit fixes as well as broader explanations on the functionality/use of generators would be appreciated.

(I included 3 examples because I have a feeling they are all just facets of the same misunderstanding. I think the question would be better served as one post rather than 3. Please comment if you disagree.)

In the first example: I understand that generator objects cannot be added explicitly, but how should the script be modified to use (unpack?) the generators?

```
>>> def f(x): return x
>>> def g(x): yield x
>>> def h(x, y): return x + y

>>> h(f(3), f(4))
7

>>> h(g(3), g(4))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 2, in h
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'generator'
```

In the second example: I'm having trouble understanding how a predefined generator object could be used to generate argument values for a function.

```
>>> print(*(x*2 for x in range(3)))
0 2 4
>>> print(x*2 for x in range(3))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fc71f050db0>
>>> print(*(yld(x) for x in range(3)))
<generator object yld at 0x7fc71f050c50> <generator object yld at 0x7fc71f050ca8> <generator object yld at 0x7fc71f050e08>
```

In this third example, how could a generator be used for a multi-argument function?

```
def yld(x): yield x
(lambda x, y: x + y)(*(yld(x) for x in range(2)))
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Generators are efficient iterators. Why do you need an iterator for summing two numbers?

Comment: How would you write `h` if `x` and `y` were lists, or tuples?

Comment: To *use* a generator you need to iterate on it.

Comment: Generators are, let's say, _things_ that generate data when you _ask them to do so_. If you pass generators around, they remain just generator objects. So, adding two _generators_ doesn't make any sense.

Comment: None of your examples are fit to use with generators, really. (

Comment: i can get the point of the first example but the others are really weird. like xy weird